# Makefile with multiple targets and creates a directory with executable

Tags: c++, compilation, makefile, g++

I don't often use makefiles therefore I only how to make basic ones. I've tried reading on how to solve my issue but I am lost. What I need is a makefile that has two targets all and test. Both of these targets need to compile the program with g++ -std=c+11 -Wall -Werror -ansi -pedantic and the only file that needs to be compiled is main.cpp when the executable is built by the compiler it needs to put the executable in a new directory called bin. And I'm assuming that if I were to use the makefile again it would need to check if bin was already created. 
I know how to create a simple makefile such as 
all:
   g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Werror -ansi -pedantic main.cpp

That creates an executable named a.out in the current directory, but that's about as far as my knowledge of makefileS go

Comment: Getting a name other than "a.out", you need compiler options ``-o foo``, which is independent of make files. You can also write ``-o ./bin/foo``, btw.

Comment: If you feel you will do such things a lot in the future, you might want to consider to make a strategic choice on the build system you want to learn (first). CMAKE is a good candidate.

Comment: OK I am not sure how correct this is but it basically did what I wanted so I created

Comment: Sorry my last comment cut off its my phones fault lol I don't know how correct this is but I created a makefile with  all: main.cpp.                    mkdir bin g++ flags -o .bin/foo.out main.cpp.                                    and it created an executable in a new folder called bin now I have another question in my directions it says I need to create another target called test that does the exact same thing, so my guess is I just copy the  "all" target and paste it under replacing "all" with "test"? PS sorry for bad formatting it sucks typing this on my phone.

Answer (score 1):

All that a `Makefile` does is specify the build dependencies, and the commands to execute to build those dependencies.

Things like creating the output directories, et. al. is not `make`'s job *per se*, but rather something that's up to the commands that makes executes to do. Neither does the `Makefile` specify where the output of the build commands go. That, of course, is specified by the actual commands that get executed. With `gcc`, for example, the `-o` option specifies where the compilation output goes. So:

```
all: bin/main

test: bin/main

bin/main: main.cpp
    mkdir -p bin
    g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Werror -ansi -pedantic -o bin/main main.cpp
```

It's very convenient to use `mkdir -p` in these situations. If the given directory does not exist, it gets created. If it already exists, `mkdir` just quietly terminates without an error.

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you good sir, I tried yours and it worked perfectly.